# ffmpeg : How to set AVFormatContext from NSData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg library in Objective-C.

I want to set AVFormatContext from NSData which contain imagedata.
I know I can set AVFormatContext with av_open_input_file().
so writing contents of NSData to a temporary file, I can do it like this.

```
[data writeToFile:@"./temp.mov" atomically:YES];
av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, "./temp.mov", NULL, 0, NULL);

.
.
.

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fm removeFileAtPath:@"./temp.mov" handler:nil];
```

but, I don't want to use temporary file.

Does anyone know smart way?

sorry my poor English.

Thanks

Comment: Did you work this thing out? I have similar problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you searched the resolve method ? Thank you!